# Howto profile performance aws dynamodb calls across many java apps

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, apm

AWS Dynamodb, lot of literature around scan vs query, using proper GSI vs LSI, etc....but nothing around how to actually analyze/profile (other than manually reviewing each one) if your current query usage patterns are 'ideal' or 'less than ideal'.

Are there any practices, dashboards, logging I may be missing to collect which queries may be less than optimal across a wide range of java apps with enough info to tackle the problem (i.e. more than just 'its slow, go figure it out'). :-)

thanks!